# Json.NET - 'JsonObject(IsReference = true)' not working

Tags: json.net

I'm serializing an object graph using Json.NET, and I'm using `JsonObject(IsReference = true)` on a few of the classes in this large hierarchy. So far this attribute has been doing what I would expect - replacing duplicate object instances in the serialized JSON with a `$ref` value.

I've just added a new class to the hierarchy with the same attribute, but I'm not getting the desired behaviour, i.e. each instance of this new class is repeated in the JSON rather than being replaced with `$ref` values.

How does Json.NET determine when to apply this referencing? The only requirement that I'm aware of is that the class has a parameterless ctr (which it does). The new class is in a separate assembly to the others, but that wouldn't make a difference would it?

**Edit**

I don't want to muddy the waters but I've been asked to provide sample code. However serialization occurs within a NoSQL database that the object graph is persisted to (RavenDB, which internally uses Json.NET). Instead, I've included an extract of the class/object graph, showing some of the pertinent properties (apologies for my poor UML):-

[image]

The classes marked with * have the `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` attribute. You can see various relationships (e.g. `Sample.Parent`, `Sample.BaselineSample` & `Concentration.Method`), and these do get replaced with `$ref` values when serialized by Json.NET.

The one that isn't working is the new `Script` class (I haven't shown its handful of properties as they are just value types). After serialization, both the `Sample.Script` and `Batch.Scripts` properties contain "full" JSON representations of the same object; I would instead expect `Sample.Script` to be replaced with a `$ref` value. (The `Batch.Methods` and `Concentration.Method` properties have an identical relationship, and the latter property *does* get replaced).

Comment: By default, objects are compared by reference, which means that unless the two instances are exactly the same reference, `IsReference` won't apply. You can change this behavior though.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I can confirm that the object instances concerned are exactly the same object reference.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a small sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Did you try serializing your structure to JSON in a test project by using JSON.NET? You can also create a https://dotnetfiddle.net/.

Comment: @IlijaDimov that worked, but I had to include the `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All` setting. My understanding is that this unconditionally replaces all duplicate object references, and the above attributes are ignored. I've since added the same setting to RavenDB and this now works too, however I'm not sure if there are implications to doing this.